Add Numbered Column by groups in R
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  SUBJECT = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
  TIME = c(7, 9, 4, 5),
  A = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
  B = c(NA, 1, 1, 1),
  C = c(1, 0, 0, 0)
)


df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = A:C, names_to = "EVENT", values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value) & value == 1) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  mutate(ADDTHIS= as.character(c('1.1', '1.2', '1', '1.1', '1.2', '2')))

  SUBJECT  TIME EVENT ADDTHIS
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
1       1     7 A     1.1    
2       1     7 C     1.2    
3       2     9 B     1      
4       3     4 A     1.1    
5       3     4 B     1.2    
6       3     5 B     2

I wish to add the ADDTHIS column so for every SUBJECT-TIME, it is 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc but then for the next time it resets.

Can you please explain the logic? Why is the 3rd value 1 and not 1.1? Why is that last row 2?

@GregorThomas because it is a new TIME in the last row, it is grouped by SUBJECT, TIME

In the dplyr sense of group_by, if you group_by(SUBJECT, TIME) then every unique combination of subject and time is treated independently. You clearly want something else, as the first subject/time group (row 1) starts with 1.1, the second subject/time group (row 3) starts with 1, the third subject/time group starts (row 4) starts with 1.1, and the fourth subject/time group (row 6) starts with 2. While your desired result clearly depends on both subject & time, it is not "grouped by" subject & time in the dplyr sense of the term.

To me, it looks like it is grouped by SUBJECT  and incrementing based on unique TIME values within the SUBJECT groups. My guess is you want the number before the decimal to count the unique TIME values, and the number after the decimal to count repetitions within the unique TIME values. And maybe if there is no repetition, you want  to omit the number after the decimal. Is that right?

@GregorThomas yes exactly

Pretty similar to Darren's:
... |>
  mutate(suffix = if(n() > 1) paste0(".", row_number()) else "", .by = c(SUBJECT, TIME)) |>
  mutate(ADDTHIS = paste0(cumsum(!duplicated(TIME)), suffix), .by = SUBJECT) |>
  select(-suffix)
#  # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   SUBJECT  TIME EVENT ADDTHIS
#     <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
# 1       1     7 A     1.1    
# 2       1     7 C     1.2    
# 3       2     9 B     1      
# 4       3     4 A     1.1    
# 5       3     4 B     1.2    
# 6       3     5 B     2  


Ooops, just assumed my ifelse was working but the length-1 test did me in. Fixed now.

You can create separate indices by different grouping variables. Then paste them together using tidyr::unite().
... %>%
  mutate(x = consecutive_id(TIME), .by = SUBJECT) %>%
  mutate(y = if(n() > 1) row_number() else NA, .by = c(SUBJECT, TIME)) %>%
  unite(ADDTHIS, x, y, sep = '.', na.rm = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   SUBJECT  TIME EVENT ADDTHIS
#     <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
# 1       1     7 A     1.1    
# 2       1     7 C     1.2    
# 3       2     9 B     1      
# 4       3     4 A     1.1    
# 5       3     4 B     1.2    
# 6       3     5 B     2


... |>
  mutate(x = consecutive_id(TIME), .by = "SUBJECT") |>
  mutate(x = if (n() > 1) paste(x, consecutive_id(EVENT), sep = ".") else as.character(x), .by = c("SUBJECT", "x"))

